# Show all options in UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have some trouble with create native share dialog. 
My goal is share link of my product by native view controller, but I can't do it. I'm trying test code:

```
NSURL *google = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"];
NSArray *activityItems = @[google];
UIActivity *activity = [UIActivity new];
UIActivityViewController *activityViewControntroller = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:@[activity]];
activityViewControntroller.excludedActivityTypes = @[];
[self presentViewController:activityViewControntroller animated:true completion:nil];
```

And I get no FB and twitter icons. In the other hand, I can see it in safari both icons and when I'm touching it I see "You need configure your account before post".
So, I want the same behavior: icons for all most-popular social networks such as VK, FB, twitter; messengers like whatsapp, viber and telegram. If some of them is not installed I want dialog "You have to log in before" and redirect to safari (e.g. for FB) to log in or open appstore (e.g. for telegram or viber) to install; otherwise I want post message with my link.
I see it like this: exclude all types from activity vc, than forcibly add all icons I need and check each of them on click manually. But in apple docs I've read that "you have to use native behavior for native items instead of create custom". So, will it be correct? Or there are other ways to solve this?

Comment: Facebook and Twitter will come only if they are already install on the device.

Comment: But in safari I can see it in despite of are installed they or not

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
-(void)clickShare:(UIButton *)sender{
    NSArray * activityItems = @[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Some initial text."], [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
    NSArray * applicationActivities = nil;
    NSArray * excludeActivities = @[];

    UIActivityViewController * activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:applicationActivities];
    activityController.excludedActivityTypes = excludeActivities;

    [self presentViewController:activityController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

this code working in my project.

Comment: What's the different with my code? Main goal -- showing ALL icons with described behavior